# Сheck if a variable exists in a dictionary Jinja2

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

I have something like this in may ansible vars:

```yaml
service_check:
    - name: service-00
      url: localhost:80
    - name: service-01
      url: localhost:81
```

I have jinja2 template for ganarate script:

```
{% for service in service_check %}
{% if service['name'] == 'service-00' %}
{% if service['url'] is defined and service['url']|length > 0 %}
URL_SERVICE-00=$({{ service['url'] }})
<some code>
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
{% if service['name'] == 'service-01' %}
{% if service['url'] is defined and service['url']|length > 0 %}
URL_SERVICE-01=$({{ service['url'] }})
<some code>
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

And I would like to check the option when the variable `url`, example for `service-00`, is not defined or it is empty. I dont know how to describe a line with this check.
Could you help me to describe the template correctly? Many thanks.

Comment: Just to be sure, regarding the condition ``if service['url'] is defined``, does it mean the attribute ``url`` might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the attribute *url* might be missing. For example, given the data,

```yaml
service_check:
  - name: service-00
    url: localhost:80
  - name: service-01
    url: localhost:81
  - name: service-02
```

add the empty string as the default attribute *url*. Add also *serial* to simplify the template

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        sc: "{{ sc|d([]) +
                [item|combine({'url': item.url|d(''),
                               'serial': item.name|split('-')|last})] }}"
      loop: "{{ service_check }}"
```

gives

```yaml
sc:
  - name: service-00
    serial: '00'
    url: localhost:80
  - name: service-01
    serial: '01'
    url: localhost:81
  - name: service-02
    serial: '02'
    url: ''
```

Then, the template can be simplified

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |-
          {% for s in sc %}
          {% if s.url|length > 0 %}
          URL_SERVICE-{{ s.serial }}=$({{ s.url }})
          <some code>
          {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: |-
    URL_SERVICE-00=$(localhost:80)
    <some code>
    URL_SERVICE-01=$(localhost:81)
    <some code>
```

You can use the data without modification if you want to. The task below gives the same result

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |-
          {% for s in service_check %}
          {% if s.url|d('')|length > 0 %}
          URL_SERVICE-{{ s.name|split('-')|last }}=$({{ s.url }})
          <some code>
          {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
```

---

Answer to the previous question: Get the list of the names first. For example, put this declaration also to your Ansible vars

```yaml
service_names: "{{ service_check|map(attribute='name')|unique }}"
```

gives

```yaml
service_names:
  - service-00
  - service-01
```

Then test the presence of a name in the list. For example,

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for service in my_services %}
          {% if service not in service_names %}
          Service name {{ service }} is missing from the list.
          {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
      vars:
        my_services:
          - URL
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: |-
    Service name url is missing from the list.
```

---

Simple version testing single value gives the same result

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% if 'url' not in service_names %}
          Service name url is missing from the list.
          {% endif %}
```

Comment: This does not work. "Simple version testing" code gives me always "Service name url is missing from the list", but i set `url` for both `service_check`

Comment: [edit] question and provide [mre].

Comment: question edited

Comment: I added the answer. Is this what you want?

Comment: thanks! it is working!